# How to escape JSON forbids octal prefixes exception in MapReduce job running in EMR

Tags: scala, hadoop, amazon-s3, gson, emr

I am running a Map job on json data which is in s3 from EMR cluster. I have run my application successfully on my local hadoop machine. But, when I tried running my job on EMR it gives me this exception.

Error: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: JSON forbids octal prefixes: 04099 at line 1 column 263

The code and data are as follows

{"_id":"101P04098","name":"Jodeco Rd/Exit 222","timezoneId":3150,"length":2.3259222706745657,"travelTimeBySpeedCategoryInHr":0.017891709774419732,"tmcType":"ROADWAY","functionalClass":1,"controlledAccess":true,"geoTag":[33.4774,-84.2158],"positiveOffset":"04099","negativeOffset":"04635","areaReference":"00009","isArterial":false,"linkList":[{"_id":127168058,"length":1.0751088091361,"directionOfLink":"FROM"},{"_id":17007579,"length":0.0759730295122253,"directionOfLink":"FROM"},{"_id":17007580,"length":1.06750755312816,"directionOfLink":"FROM"},{"_id":17007581,"length":0.10733287889808,"directionOfLink":"FROM"}]}

`object TmcListReader {
     val gson: Gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingStrategy(new FieldNamingStrategy {
    override def translateName(f: Field): String = {
      if (f.getName == "id") "_id" else f.getName}}).create }
  class TmcListReader {
    import TmcListReader._
    def readLocationsInTables(input: Source, tmcTables: List[String]): List[String] = {
  val tmcLocations: 
       List[String] =input.getLines().map(gson.fromJson(_,classOf[TmcLocation]).getId).toList
    tmcLocations.filter { location => tmcTables contains location.table}
  }`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in JSON, you shouldn't left pad numbers with zeros. So in the above case the '04099' probably needs to become '4099'.

You may have already figured this out, or may otherwise not need the answer, but comparing my issue to yours helped me figure out what was wrong, so I thought I'd share in case anyone else had the same question. In my case, I had a '06' for a month that needed to become '6'.